# Amazon S3 からファイルを直接ダウンロードするようなWebAPIはどのように作れば良いか？

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3, webapi

ASP.NET .NET Frameworkを利用してWebAPIを開発しています。
クラウドストレージ(AWSのS3)にファイルを配置し、それをダウンロードさせるWebAPIを作りたいと考えています。
以下のような形で作成し、ダウンロードできることは確認しました。

しかしこのやり方だとWebAPIのサーバーにファイルができるまで呼び出し元が待たされることになります。
S3から一時ファイルを作らずに一気にダウンロードさせる方法はないでしょうか？

```
    [Route("download/s3")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetS3Data(string key)
    {
        // データベースにアクセスし、keyからバケット名、ダウンロード元パス、ダウンロード先パスを取得
        IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2);

        GetBucketLocationRequest request1 = new GetBucketLocationRequest
        {
            BucketName = バケット名
        };

        // リージョン取得
        string location = client.GetBucketLocation(request1).Location.Value;
        client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(location));
            
        TransferUtilityDownloadRequest request2 = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest
        {
            BucketName = バケット名,
            Key = ダウンロード元パス,
            FilePath = サーバー内のダウンロード先パス
        };

        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
        fileTransferUtility.Download(request2);

        //ファイルを開く
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlDestPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            //ファイルを読み込むバイト型配列を作成する
            byte[] bs = new byte[fs.Length];
            //ファイルの内容をすべて読み込む
            fs.Read(bs, 0, bs.Length);
            fs.Close();
            // 一時ファイル削除
            File.Delete(dlDestPath);
            return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(bs));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS SDK for .NETの[`Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility`クラス](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=S3/TTransferUtility.html&tocid=Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility)には`Download`メソッドのほかに`OpenStream`メソッドが用意されています。こちらを使用して得られたstreamをWebAPIのレスポンスに渡せば、ASP.NET側がストリーム間コピーをしてくれるはずです。

---

全く別のアプローチで、AWS S3には[presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)という機能があります。こちらを使用するとダウンロード用URLを生成することができるので、WebAPIのレスポンスとしてそのアドレスにリダイレクトしてやると、サーバーを介さずクライアントが直接S3からダウンロードするようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。OpenStreamメソッドを使ったダウンロードが実現できました。回答に対応内容を記述しておきます。

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreamメソッドを使ってAPI側を実現できました。

```
using(var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
{
    var stream = transferUtility.OpenStream(bucketName, filePath);

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(stream)
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "testfile.zip"
        };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    var response = ResponseMessage(result);

    return response;
}
```